# when running `udevadm test`: `no db file to read /run/udev/data/+gpio_sw:PA7: No such file or directory`

Tags: udev, devices, sysfs

I am trying to write an udev rule that matches a GPIO Pin of my Orange Pi (the GPIOs use the gpio-sunxi kernel module). My ultimate goal is to let users who are member of a particular group access GPIOs. This is the device in question:

```
$ udevadm info -a /sys/class/gpio_sw/PA7

...

  looking at device '/devices/platform/gpio_sw.11/gpio_sw/PA7':
    KERNEL=="PA7"
    SUBSYSTEM=="gpio_sw"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{cfg}=="0"
    ATTR{drv}=="0"
    ATTR{data}=="0"
    ATTR{pull}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/gpio_sw.11':
    KERNELS=="gpio_sw.11"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="gpio_sw"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Even without adding any rules, I get the error mentioned in the title:

```
$ udevadm test /sys/class/gpio_sw/PA7
...
rules contain 196608 bytes tokens (16384 * 12 bytes), 25689 bytes strings
14493 strings (120055 bytes), 12021 de-duplicated (96839 bytes), 2473 trie nodes used
no db file to read /run/udev/data/+gpio_sw:PA7: No such file or directory
no db file to read /run/udev/data/+platform:gpio_sw.11: No such file or directory
Unload module index
...

ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/gpio_sw.11/gpio_sw/PA7
SUBSYSTEM=gpio_sw
USEC_INITIALIZED=271329566
```

Comparing this to `udevadm test /sys/block/mmcblk0`, I don't get those errors, but instead more infos about the applied actions before `Unload module index`. At the end, I see the results as expected, e.g. `DEVLINKS=...`. I don't see anything like this for `PA7`, whether I add my own rules or not.

- What information should be in `/run/udev/data/+gpio_sw:PA7` and `/run/udev/data/+platform:gpio_sw.11`? Why is it missing?
- Can I work around needing it?

Comment: In the meantime, I have worked around the problem with an init script